# Posting a bad answer to preserve information

Tags: discussion, answers

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195601/flask-error-typeerror-run-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-host) in a review queue and I noticed that the OP had commented with their solution but the post still had no answers. So I replied with a comment encouraging them to post an answer explaining the solution for others.

However after doing so I realised that the post is 2 years old, the OP is erratically active on the site and the link was broken. I used archive.org to find a working version of the page from when the OP posted that they found their solution there.

Then I decided to post an answer. I'm familiar with Python, but not flask. So the best I could do was quote the snippet that contains the command OP mentioned, and cite them saying that using it solved their answer. It's clearly a poor answer, as it's not clear how you use it, how it applies to the case OP brought up or anything like that. I commented to that effect, saying that anyone who sees this answer would ideally post a more useful answer that is explained properly.

My question is whether this is a good idea or not. I merely want to provide more information than is currently available (a broken link and a reference to a command's name), but should I be posting an answer knowing that it has a severe quality deficiency?

Comment: You can mark the answer as [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) if you're unsure about the post and want to invite the community to contribute to make it a better answer.

Comment: Why do you think you need to "preserve information"?  The question survived 2 years already, little reason to assume it won't make the next 10.  Questions are only auto-deleted when they are not upvoted.

Comment: @SleuthEye That is a good suggestion, and may ultimately be the answer.

Comment: @HansPassant That's not SO policy. Age shouldn't diminish the usefulness of a question with 4 upvotes (the score it had when I found it). If the question isn't subject to autodeletion surely it's being kept intentionally?

Comment: No idea what you mean.  A question never gets to be more useful when somebody adds a bad answer.  It gets worse because somebody might find it and lose a day of his life on it.  There is a pretty decent signal in not seeing an answer.  It means "there is no answer, do this differently".

Comment: @HansPassant Well that sentiment isn't applicable in this case, there is clearly an answer that works. Just no-one has done the legwork to make it a real, useful answer. There's information that leads to a solution, even if it's poorly explained.

Comment: If you think it is important that this question gets a good answer then simply put a bounty on it.